# How can I change Joomla! template folder name?

Tags: templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a **Joomla! 2.5** website and I want to change **beez_20** template folder name, I followed this 3 step solution but it didn't work.

1. Change the template folder name
2. Change the name of the template in the `templateDetails.xml` file to match the folder name
3. *Extensions->Discover->Install*

I want change the 'Bluestork' template folder name too, this is administrator template.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not just these steps here. You need to

1. Change the foldername ( templates/FOLDERNAME )
2. Change the [name] in templateDetails.xml in several places (Use Replace Tool)
3. Change the Language File: en-GB.tpl_NEW-NAME.ini
4. (If it is Admin Template, change administrator/templates/FOLDERNAME too)

Have Fun... Reply in the case of issue

Answer (score 0):

Do the same thing, just in the admin template folder.